# how do I fix Expected 0 arguments, but got 1 in createDrawerNavigator

Tags: typescript, react-native, navigation-drawer

Please help me to fix error with drawer navigator

here is the code of **drawer.tsx**

error: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. in  createDrawerNavigator function

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import AboutStack from "./aboutStack";
import HomeStack from "./homeStack";

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStack,
  },
  About: {
    screen: AboutStack,
  },
});
```

screenshot of the error:

[drawer.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPqat.png)

Comment: I think you are looking at the docs for [v4](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/drawer-based-navigation). The latest is [v6](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation#minimal-example-of-drawer-based-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `createDrawerNavigator` doesn't take in the screens directly. What you need to do is use the `DrawerNavigator` returned by this function as a component inside the return statement (if using functional components, otherwise inside the render function if using class components) like a normal component. And then provide screens as children.

You can check it out here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/#minimal-example-of-drawer-based-navigation